# How to convert encoded Wordpress footer to PHP and vice versa

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding

I'm trying to decode Wordpress PHP footer. I used an online decoder (unphp.net) to convert:

```
<?php ${"G\x4cO\x42\x41LS"}["\x70\x71\x78\x67\x70\x79\x78\x69\x6aa\x67\x67"]="f\x6f\x6f\x74er\x4e\x61\x76";$vblwdpykffb="\x6d\x65\x6e\x75\x5f\x63\x6c\x61\x73\x73";echo "\t";$nrcdlvfsn="\x66\x6fo\x74e\x72\x4e\x61v";$jopfoesskt="\x6de\x6e\x75\x5fcla\x73\x73";$lxpnqlh="\x6de\x6e\x75\x5fc\x6c\x61\x73\x73";get_sidebar("fo\x6ft\x65\x72");$gmtipnfwdy="\x66\x6fo\x74\x65\x72N\x61\x76";echo "\t\n\t<div i\x64\x3d\"f\x6fote\x72-\x62\x6f\x74to\x6d\">\n\t\t\x3c\x64\x69v c\x6cass\x3d\"\x63o\x6e\x74\x61in\x65\x72 c\x6cea\x72fix\x22>\n\x20\x20\x20  \x20 \x20\n\x20   \x20 \x20 \t\x3c\x64i\x76\x20cl\x61\x73\x73\x3d\"a\x6c\x69gn\x6cef\x74\x22\x3e\n\t\t\t\t\x3c\x61 h\x72e\x66\x3d\"ht\x74p://\x77\x77w\x2e3z\x61r.\x69r/\x22\x20\x74ar\x67e\x74\x3d\x22_\x62\x6ca\x6ek\"\x3e<\x64i\x76 c\x6c\x61\x73s\x3d\"\x77\x70\"></di\x76>\x3c/\x61\x3e\n\t\t\t</\x64\x69\x76\x3e\n\x20\x20\x20\x20 \x20\x20\x20\n\t\t\t";${$jopfoesskt}="\x62o\x74to\x6d-\x6ea\x76";${$nrcdlvfsn}="";if(function_exists("\x77p\x5fn\x61v_m\x65nu"))${${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x70\x71\x78g\x70\x79x\x69j\x61\x67\x67"]}=wp_nav_menu(array("t\x68e\x6d\x65_\x6c\x6fc\x61t\x69\x6fn"=>"\x66o\x6f\x74\x65r-\x6de\x6eu","c\x6f\x6et\x61ine\x72"=>"","f\x61l\x6c\x62ac\x6b\x5fcb"=>"","me\x6eu\x5f\x63l\x61\x73s"=>${$vblwdpykffb},"\x65\x63\x68\x6f"=>false,"dep\x74\x68"=>"1"));if(""==${$gmtipnfwdy})show_page_menu(${$lxpnqlh});else echo(${${"\x47L\x4f\x42\x41\x4c\x53"}["pq\x78\x67\x70\x79x\x69j\x61\x67g"]});echo "\n   \x20\x20\x20\x20  \x20\x20 \n\t\t\x3c/div>\x20\x3c!-- \x65n\x64 \x2e\x63onta\x69ne\x72 --\x3e\n\t</\x64i\x76\x3e\x20\x3c\x21-- \x65n\x64\x20\x23\x66\x6f\x6f\x74e\x72-b\x6f\x74t\x6fm\x20--\x3e\n\t\t\t\n\t";wp_footer();echo "\x3c/\x62\x6fdy>\n</\x68\x74ml>\n";?>
```

to

```
<?php ${"GLOBALS"}["pqxgpyxijagg"]="footerNav";$vblwdpykffb="menu_class";echo " ";$nrcdlvfsn="footerNav";$jopfoesskt="menu_class";$lxpnqlh="menu_class";get_sidebar("footer");$gmtipnfwdy="footerNav";echo "    
<div id="footer-bottom">
    <div class="container clearfix">

        <div class="alignleft">
            <a href="http://www.3zar.com/" target="_blank"><div class="wp"></div></a>
        </div>

        ";${$jopfoesskt}="bottom-nav";${$nrcdlvfsn}="";if(function_exists("wp_nav_menu"))${${"GLOBALS"}["pqxgpyxijagg"]}=wp_nav_menu(array("theme_location"=>"footer-menu","container"=>"","fallback_cb"=>"","menu_class"=>${$vblwdpykffb},"echo"=>false,"depth"=>"1"));if(""==${$gmtipnfwdy})show_page_menu(${$lxpnqlh});else echo(${${"GLOBALS"}["pqxgpyxijagg"]});echo "

    </div> <!-- end .container -->
</div> <!-- end #footer-bottom -->

";wp_footer();echo "</body></html>";?>
```

Can you tell me what is the encode name used in original footer? Can you name an encoder to convert PHP code to this encoding?

Comment: I don't understand... Is your problem decoding or encoding? What are you trying to encode? What name are you looking that's not listed in unphp.net? What's the problem with the decoded part? I'm not sure what it does, but the decoded code seems pretty awful, if not plainly nasty.

Comment: I want to convert these two to each other, and I want to know what is encoding name, Is it HEX or..?